# Does anyone know why TimeZonesSidKey field in Organization sObject is not available to be patched by Salesforce REST API?

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to update the Timezone of the organization using the Salesforce REST API as DML operations on Organization is not permitted using apex. However, the TimeZoneSidKey field doesn't seem to be exposed via the Salesforce REST API. Any clue why is it not or are there other ways to update the same apart from using SOAP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be patched; I just tested it. Make sure the field spelling is correct, and contains a legal value, such as "America/Denver".

[image]

Comment: That's strange. I tried it again and it still doesn't work. To be sure, I fired a GET request on the Organization and I get all the parameters except the TimeZoneSidKey. Also, I don't see this parameter in the Salesforce documentation for REST API - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Organization/patch-organization-id

Comment: Okay, I got it ! TimeZoneSidKey is only available from version 43 and not in earlier versions. Thanks @sfdcfox !